# PHP how to use the @Category tag in DocBlocks

Tags: php, documentation

can someone explain or give some examples how to use the @Category Tag the right way ? PHPDocumentator is not parsing the Tag.

How does an correct File-DocBlock and Class-DocBlock looks like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but... From the [manual](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.category.pkg.html):

> The @category tag is used to organize
>   groups of packages together. This is
>   directly applicable to the
>   XML:DocBook/peardoc2 Converter, and
>   can be used by other converters. Other
>   Converters packaged with phpDocumentor
>   ignore the category, but this may
>   change in future versions. It is also
>   possible to dynamically specify
>   category using the -dc,
>   --defaultcategoryname command-line switch.

```
/**
 * Page-Level DocBlock
 * @package MyPackage
 * @category mycategory
 */

/**
 * @global array used for stuff
 */
function mine()
{
    global $baz;
    ...
}
```

Also, here's a [sample of the proper way to write PEAR code](http://www.developertutorials.com/pear-manual/standards.sample.html), including DocBlocks with @category.

Please post some sample code that's not parsing -- that may help in answering what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find any useful examples on how to use the @category tag. It made sense to me to use it to represent the MVC layers using that tag ie:

```
/**
 * Layout or template
 * 
 * @category view
 */

/**
 * Database representation of the user
 * 
 * @category model
 */

/**
 * Login actions
 * 
 * @category controller
 */
```

That's how I use it.